# type +'a t in Ocaml Map Library?

Tags: module, dictionary, types, ocaml

I'm working with Ocaml's built-in Map library for a problem set, and I'm having trouble accessing the datatype of a map itself. This is supposed to be the third implementation of a dictionary (the first two being a list and an unbalanced binary search tree), and part of the functor I have to implement is "type dict", which is the datatype of the actual dictionary. For list, type dict was (D.key * D.value) list; for the tree, type dict was Empty | Branch((D.key * D.value), dict, dict). The Ocaml documentation says:

```
type +'a t 
The type of maps from type key to type 'a.
```

This seems like what I need, but I can't seem to use it correctly. M is my Map.Make module, by the way. I've tried

```
type dict = M.t
type dict = M.+D.value t
type dict = M.+
```

But I keep getting error messages. Can anyone help? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7):

`+` is a variance annotation, it is not part of the name. The syntax of parametrized type is `param type` or `(param, param, ...) type` in OCaml : `int list`, `(int, string) Hashbl.t`. What you want here is `D.value M.t`.

Comment: How is '+' not a syntactic construct?

Comment: "Each type parameter may be prefixed by a variance constraint + (resp. -) indicating that the parameter is covariant (resp. contravariant)." from http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual016.html. It allows/disallows sub-typing in the variant and object system.

Comment: Of course, my wording was wrong. Of course nearly everything is "a syntaxic construct", and I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! D.value M.t works! Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4):

You can find out yourself by asking the ocaml compiler: `ocamlc -i file.ml`

To create a map via Map.Make from the standard ocaml library, this file would look like this (for a map from int to 'a):

```
module Intmap = Map.Make (struct
   type t = int
   let compare = Pervasives.compare
end)
```

The ocaml compiler will give you something like this (when calling `ocamlc -i mymap.ml`):

```
module Intmap :
   sig
      type key = int
      type +'a t
      val empty : 'a t
      ...
end
```